# Google Maps API3 with default Popup & Marker?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to show the default Google Maps icon and popup on a custom map?

The default one with the address, title directions nearby etc etc.

This is how i've currently got it set up and working fine apart from the marker..

```
 var map;
 jQuery(function($) {
    function initialize() {
      var styles = [
        {
          stylers: [
            { "saturation": -100 }
          ]
        }
      ];
      var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
        {name: "Styled Map"});
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.6468, 37.581),
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
        }
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
                  mapOptions);

      //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
      map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
      map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
   }

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to show the default Google Maps icon and popup on a custom map?

The default marker is easy, see [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers), but the answer for the Google Maps default infowindow is no,  but you can create your own [infowindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows) that looks similar and has similar functionality.